# jQuery iViewer to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to initials the jQuery iViewer via AngularJS directives. The initialisation in jQuery is as follows

```
$("#viewer2").iviewer(
              {
                  src: "test_image2.jpg",
                  zoom_min:'100',
                  zoom_max:'400'
              });
```

My Angular Skeleton for the directive is as follows

```
var vm = angular.module('vModule',[]);
vm.directive('vModuleConfig',function(){
return {
    restrict:'A',
    link:function(scope,element,attrs){
    // What to do here for initialisation
          }
       }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the same code in link method an passing element instead of the id? Like this $(element).iviewer(...);

Comment: Seems to work fine. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n02vvcdd/3/

Comment: thanks i figured it out after sometime of posting the question , why do you put $ in front of element ? it works without that also.

Comment: Yep, you are right, it should work without it.